Auto-unlocking gnome-keyring does not work when using pam_sss
The Gnome Keyrings "Login" and "Default" are not unlocked automatically on my Linux Mint 22 machine. This is an LDAP user account and login goes throughg pam_sss.so (SSSD). The journal seems to indicate that pam_gnome_keyring.so does not receive the entered password (gkr-pam: no password is available for user), but I do not understand why:
$ sudo journalctl -b | egrep -i 'keyring|pam'
Okt 11 17:24:16 promoter lightdm[29410]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Okt 11 17:24:17 promoter lightdm[29526]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "fritz"
Okt 11 17:24:22 promoter lightdm[29526]: pam_sss(lightdm:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= user=fritz
Okt 11 17:24:22 promoter lightdm[29526]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user
Okt 11 17:24:22 promoter lightdm[29526]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user fritz(uid=30108) by (uid=0)
Okt 11 17:24:22 promoter lightdm[29526]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly

Here's the (hopefully) relevant sections of my PAM auth config. I could provide more, but I don't think that common-account, common-session, and common-password are relevant to this question:
$ cat /etc/pam.d/lightdm
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
-auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
-auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
-auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
#session required        pam_loginuid.so
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
-session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
-session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
-session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password

$ /etc/pam.d/cat common-auth 
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    required    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config

Further observations:

The journal message gkr-pam: no password is available for user also appears when unlocking the screensaver from source cinnamon-screensaver-pam-helper.


Okay, the problem apparently was that I swapped the order in which pam_sss and pam_unix were invoked, some time ago. When I change them back to their original order using pam-auth-update --force to revert any local modifications, it works:
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
[...]

Background: I did this because the same username exists both locally and in LDAP with the same user ID. By default, only SSSD should handle the authentication in order to obtain a Kerberos ticket. If pam_unix successfully authenticates the user, pam_sss is skipped by the success=2 argument and SSSD does not get the password and cannot obtain a ticket. (The local user is kind of a backup in case SSSD ever fails or I am offline for a long time. Not sure how SSSD reacts in that case).
In order to fix this, and force pam_sss to handle the authentication, I simply changed the password of the local account to something different. That way, when I try to log in with the LDAP password, pam_unix will fail and fall back to pam_sss, which will succeed and obtain a  Kerberos ticket. If I want to log in with the local "backup" account, I simply enter the other password and pam_unix will succeed, skipping pam_sss.
In hindsight, I should probably just set a secure root password to allow recovery if SSSD fails, and get rid of the local unix user in /etc/shadow
Hopefully this is helpful for someone in the future.
